# What does it mean by " I umbrella the rain."

Tags: meaning

I don't understand the sentence above.
I know that "umbrella" is noun. But in the sentence above, It is used like "verb."
How is it possible?

Comment: English speakers are notorious for "verbing nouns", so _I umbrella the rain_ simply means this: "I use an umbrella to keep myself dry when it rains". All it takes to figure this kind of stuff out is a little imagination.

Comment: Sounds like someone is playing on “I ♥ rainbows” by making “I ☂ rain” out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you hear/read that?

"Umbrella" can't be used as a verb like that in "standard" English, and I don't know of any slang or dialect or anything in which that's possible either.

If that sentence was really generated by a native English speaker, then my guess is that they meant the deliberately bizarre and awkward misuse of the word as a joke...?

Comment: Any noun can be used as a verb. That's one way that language changes. Look at all the current "standard, acceptable, and idiotomatic" stupidities: "We privilege the underdog", "I regifted the sweater my grandma gave me", "I googled this topic and got 1,000,000 hits". **Never tell native Anglophones what's not possible in English**: you'll always be wrong. Just read the _Cambridge Grammar of the English Language_ if you want to see what's possible: _Almost anything goes_. English is often a byproduct of Murphy's Law of Language Lapses (lapsus linguae): If it can be uttered, it will be.

Comment: What would you do with a noun that's a neologism? People would freely verb it -- check contemporary writing!

Comment: I aint no prescriptivist; My point was just to reassure the original poster that, if that sentence really was generated by a native English speaker, then they were deliberately expressing the idea in a way that "sounds weird", as a joke. Do you disagree?

Comment: Also I doubt it *is* genuine; It'd've been way more likely to be in continuous or simple past or something rather than simple present if it was, so... Hey, Bag-yonghyeon (or however you transliterate that)! Don't worry, "I umbrella the rain" *isn't* "correct" English.

Comment: @Bill _Any noun can be used as a verb._ A little impractical. When there's an established verb form already, verbing the noun is probably best avoided. And some nouns should probably not be considered for verbing on aesthetic grounds (I've heard 'giraffing', but only from a wag): plethora  jurisprudence larceny dachshund loyalty patriotism misery shrewdness volery glaring ostentation seafood pyruvic acid, mineral water, He who must not be named [sic].

Comment: Sounds like a line of poetry to me, deliberately using a non-standard form for poetic effect.